# TclError: image "pyimage68" doesn't exist

Tags: image, tkinter, photoimage

Had made a tkinter window named `Mainpage` of which the snippet is present below:

```python
def mainpage():
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    

root = tk.Tk()

image=Image.open("logo2.png")                                 
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)                             

lab = tk.Label(root, image=photo, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)  # <----Error is coming for this line in the next code
lab.image=photo
lab.place(x=460,y=245)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Search",font="CenturyGothic",fg="Darkred",width="70", 
height="24",command=veryuseful)
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="gold.png") 
button.config(image=img1,compound="center")
button.place(x=850,y=340)
root.mainloop()
```

There is no problem in the code whatsoever.
But, when I import this file to another code an error occurs:

```python
import Mainpage  # <----imported the file here
condition=0        

     for i in d:
        
        if i[3]==username:
            if i[4]==password:
                head=tk.Label(win, text="Welcome to Library X",fg="Light blue",bg="Black" ,font=("Arial",12))
                head.grid(column=1, row=7)
                condition=1
                
                break
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Wrong Password!")
                condition=2
                break
        else:
            continue
            condition=0
            
    if condition==0:
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Wrong Username!") 
        
    if condition==1:
        
        Mainpage.mainpage()   # <------Used the function mainpage from file
```

A error comes called "pyimage" I have seen the error many times but this time it is strange
The TCL error is : `"pyimage10" doesn't exist`

And as edit try it again it changes to "pyimage16" and then it keeps on adding 6 to the no. beside pyimage...

If you know the solution to this problem I shall be forever grateful.
I have already tried:

1. provided full path to the file
2. used a reference to the image
3. restarted the kernal

As I said, the mainpage file is working normally when I run it but...the problem is in tkinter when I import it to another file.

Comment: In the code that imports `Mainpage`, does it _also_ create an instance of `Tk`? What you describe is one of the problems when you create more than once instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Is the indentation of that `mainpage()` definition correct? It looks highly suspicious.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't expect there to be more than one call to the `mainloop()` method across a whole program.

Comment: Bryan Oakley can you pls tell how I can add more than one widget without adding instances of Tk()? I am a beginner so can u pls tell...

Comment: Donal Fellows, the indentations are right, only when I copied it here there might be one or two mistakes and I have used mainloop() only one time...any other suggestions friend?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to my problem...if you ever have pyimage error:

Change-

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

To-

```
root = tk.Toplevel()
```

If this does not work, try:

1. Restarting your kernel
2. Provide full path to the image file
3. Provide a reference to the image

If your problem is solved an upvote would be appreciated :)